# "How deep" or "How deeply"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, adjectives, adverbs

In the sentence:

> How **deep** or **deeply** should I study something?

Which of the two is more appropriate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that context, it's *deeply*.

*Deep* is an adjective, so can only be used to describe the quality of a noun:

> How deep is the water?

*Deeply* is an adverb, so can only be used to modify a verb:

> Were you thinking deeply?

*Deep* is often used instead of *deeply*, to the extent that it is largely accepted without comment. However, I've never heard it the other way around. "What a deeply question" is just plain wrong.

Comment: Though you are right in your description of plain *deep* often being used as an adverb, I just want to emphasize for non-native speakers that this is definitely seen as informal, so make sure to avoid this in a formal situation.

Comment: It's not just deep/deeply where the adjectival form (no -ly) is sometimes also used as an adverb. This happens with some frequency in English--part of a much larger trend of simplifying inflected forms. As Kosmonaut notes, this is an informal usage (but check back in another 100 years!)

Comment: '_Deep_ is an adjective, so can only be used to describe the quality of a noun' and '_Deep_ is often used instead of _deeply_, to the extent that it is largely accepted without comment.' is over-simplistic. AHDEL, Collins, RHK Webster's ... all list the perfectly acceptable adverbial usage/s. The distribution of the flat adverb is not identical: they worked deep into the night / dig deep / run deep / play deep.

Comment: @Kosmonaut I want to correct your misinforming of non-native speakers that the use of _deep_ as an adverb is always better avoided at least in formal writing. Sometimes, it and not _deeply_ is the correct choice.

Comment: @res '[T]his is an informal (strongly hinting at less than totally acceptable) usage'. The flat adverb _deep_ is sometimes the only acceptable form. Check in a dictionary. And this is true with other flat adverbs in certain situations. 'We arrived at London and then flew direct to Athens' has a different meaning from 'We arrived at London and then flew directly to Athens' .

Answer (score 7):

*Deeply* is probably better in this context, because it's an an adverb of manner or degree, and is commonly used as an intensifier. In this case it can indicate the degree or intensity of the studying.

*Deep*, when used as an adverb, is usually used as an adverb of place.

While *deep* can also be an adjective, *deeply*, of course, is not used as an adjective.

So:

- She understands the concept deeply. (*Deeply* is being used as an intensifier or adverb of manner or degree.)
- She has a deep understanding of the concept. (*Deep* is being used as an adjective.)
- They are travelling deep underground. (*Deep* is being used as an adverb of place/location.)
- You're going to need to dig deep. (*Deep* is being used as an adverb of place/location, and also as a resultative.)
- How deep should I go? (*Deep* is being used as an adverb of place/location.)

This is not necessarily an exact science, and it's certainly not a question of formality or informality. In fact, there's an argument for "How deep should I study something" if *deep* is thought of as resultative – i.e. *as a result of studying something, I will be deep inside of it*, which is an expression of metaphorical location. However, a similar concept can be expressed with "deeply immersed in it", which may seem at first blush like location but is probably better characterized as an expression of the intensity or degree of the immersion.

In the end it may be a question of whether it's the intensity or degree of the verb process or the locative result of the verb process that's being emphasized.

Comment: I'm sorry that this far better answer should be 3 - 6+ down against a deficient one rather than 6 - 0 up. It's not good for the site.

Comment: Excellent explanation and examples to it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Deep is accepted as an adverb in the Oxford English Dictionary. I think deeply, while still accepted, is a hypercorrection. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

**In what depth…?** is what an educated native speaker might find more elegant. (And an uneducated native speaker doesn’t do much studying.)